# Длина большого файла через функцию filelength

Tags: c++, файлы, файловая-система

Никак не могу понять почему, если хочу узнать длину файла ~3GB в байтах вот так:

```
FILE * f;
errno_t err = fopen_s(&f, "a.iso", "rb");
if (f == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}  
unsigned long int size = filelength(fileno(f));
cout << size << endl;
```

то мне выдаёт максимально возможное число для типа `unsigned long int` 4 294 967 295. С маленькими файлами всё нормально (правда я там `int` использую). Функция `filelength` объявлена в `<io.h>`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что тут неправильно.

Comment: а как объявлена функция  filelength?

Comment: она стандартная отсюда #include <io.h>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, если файл большой :), то для этого есть, например, `_filelengthi64` (подробнее [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246860%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)).

Comment: Cпасибо filelengthi64  - то что и нужно было )

Comment: Ну, если устраивает - помечайте ответ как принятый :)

Comment: Точно, пометил уже, сори просто пока тут не освоился

Answer (score 6):

> Функция filelength возвращает длину файла в байтах. Возвращаемое значение -1L свидетельствует об ошибке  и errno устанавливается в EBADF, чтобы указать на неверный файловый handle.
>
> Надо помнить, что возвращаемая переменная имеет тип long.

Знаковый long - это до 2 ГБ. Если размер файла больше, то произошло бы переполнение, но функция это обрабатывает и сообщает об ошибке, вернув -1.

> Да, так и есть если я пишу long int size = filelength(fileno(f)); То возвращает -1L , но я беру unsigned long int а тут макс значение 4 294 967 295, вот оно почему то и выводится хотя файл сам меньше, ~ 3gb

Потому что функции всё равно, какому типу ты присваиваешь результат. Она всегда возвращает long, что означает -1 для слишком больших файлов. Когда ты присваиваешь это в unsigned long, ты получаешь беззнаковое число с таким же набором битов. Все единичные биты в знаковом числе означают -1, а в беззнаковом - максимум.

Comment: Да, так и есть если я пишу

Comment: Да, так и есть если я пишу  long int size = filelength(fileno(f)); 
То возвращает -1L , но я беру unsigned long int а тут макс значение
 4 294 967 295, вот оно почему то и выводится хотя файл сам меньше, ~ 3gb

Comment: @Alex, битовое значение  4 294 967 295 в 32-bit unsigned то же самое, что у -1 в 32-bit signed. Ищите другую, 64-bit функцию.

Comment: @Alex, обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за понятное объяснение